# Why is the paragraph element is not allowed in the h1 element for xhtml strict?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

As we know `h1` and `p` elements are block elements. To quote an article I read:

> H1 is a block element like P, but H1 and P can only have inline
>   content inside of them, unlike other block elements like forms and
>   divs. Therefore, you can't nest headings inside paragraphs (and if you
>   think about it a heading really should never be in a paragraph).

And I want to know why the `p` element can not be nested within an `h1` element and why the `h1` element can not be nested within a paragraph element? People just say the reason is at [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5).

In that link, I could not find where it  mentions which tag is not allowed in `h1` element.

Are there articles providing us with insight to which elements are not allowed in which elements for all doctype version (HTML 4.0.1, HTML5, XHTML strict,etc) ?

Comment: take it up with the powers that be. The good news is xhtml was short lived and rapidly dying.

Comment: Did you read the portion that you quoted? Because it looks like it was written precisely to answer your question.

Comment: you mean spend more time on HTML5 instead of xhtml ?

Comment: @Lenny: The irony is that this has nothing to do with XHTML specifically. HTML may be alive and going strong, but joke's on you: it isn't allowed in HTML either, which actually happens to be *why* it isn't allowed in XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn No, the jokes on me because no one cares. I loved XHTML Strict. I was so excited that html was going to be clean. I supported browsers not supporting bad code, but popular opinion was loose HTML5. So go ahead and put paragraphs inside of your headers it'll still work no one will ever know.

Comment: @Lenny: That's OK because it won't work, period. But the real good news is, if XHTML's appeal to you lies in its syntactic rules, then those still live on in XHTML5 - just write your HTML5 markup in XML syntax and serve it with the appropriate MIME type, and modern browsers will be happy to treat it with strict error handling as they do with any XML. It's not an XHTML standard in its own right, but as far as syntax is concerned it'll qualify as XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It was really more about consistency in closures than semantics, but both were / are nice. What it was really about was the brief year or so when it looked like I would never have to adopt someone else's awful code again. In HTML5 you don't have to close html, head, body, p, dt, dd, li, option, thead, th, tbody, tr, td, tfoot, or colgroups. People can makes some really ugly code if they want and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 6):

HTML actually isn't just a language of block and inline elements but a semantical description of your website. Screenreaders for example analyse the structure and provide diferent functionality on headlines, tables, lists and so on. So it's important to take a look at the semantics of your website and just if it's inline or block.

p and h1 are semantical tags instead of a div and span which are pretty much just containers for you to apply styles. P means it's a paragraph of text and paragraphs don't have headlines (headlines are positioned above paragraphs!). And headlines don't have paragraphs either. So it would just break with the semantical meaning to allow them being placed inside each other.

Comment: there is a huge difference between being able to do it and being allowed to do it. Or making sense at all. And yes, a header inside a footer might even make sense :)

Comment: btw. try to put a table inside a p and you'll see that not everything works ;)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FNsGm3%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 Why there is a lot of error

Comment: The result is loaded inside an iframe and not validated here ;) But here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FNsGm3%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices